# adjoint representations

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras, adjoint-operators

I am trying to work out the adjoint representations of

$$H=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0 \\
0 & -1
\end{array}
\right),
X = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 1 \\
0 & 0
\end{array}
\right),
Y = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 0 \\
1 & 0
\end{array}
\right) .$$

but I am not exactly sure how to do it.

So far I have worked out

(ad$H$)($H$) = $0$

(ad$H$)($X$) = $\left(\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 2 \\
0 & 0
\end{array}
\right)$

(ad$H$)($Y$) = $\left(\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 0 \\
-2 & 0
\end{array}
\right)$

Comment: Does $(ad H)(X)$ mean $HX-XH$?

Comment: yes it does sorry should have mentioned that

Comment: Then the answers are ok.

Comment: but how would you combine them into one matrix representation for adH?

Comment: So, $ad H$ is a map on $2\times 2$ matrices? Is it linear? If it is, then one can represent it by $4\times 4$ matrix with respect to a basis in the space of $2\times 2$ matrices. What would be a basis? $X$ and $Y$ could be in it, maybe also $H$. But probably instead of $H$ it is better to take some other matrix, actually two as $2\times 2$ matrices form $4$ dimensional space.

Comment: I think it is supposed to be a 3x3 matrix but would it be the same idea?

Comment: It seems that you didn't tell the whole story. You should say where is $adH$ acting. Is it on the space spanned by $H, X$ and $Y$? If it is so, then you can use the idea from the answer and write the matrix w.r.t. basis $(H,X,Y)$.

Answer (score 1):

Let
$$ E_{11}=\left( \begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0\\ 0 & 0 \end{array}\right),
E_{12}=\left( \begin{array}{cc} 0 & 1\\ 0 & 0 \end{array}\right),
E_{21}=\left( \begin{array}{cc} 0 & 0\\ 1 & 0 \end{array}\right),\quad \text{and}\quad
E_{22}=\left( \begin{array}{cc} 0 & 0\\ 0 & 1 \end{array}\right).$$
This is a basis of $\mathbb M_{2}$.
For each pair $(i,j)$ express $adH(E_{ij})$ as a linear combination of matrices from the basis. For instance
$$ adH(E_{12})=2 E_{12}.$$
More generally,
$$ adH(E_{ij})=\alpha_{1}^{(ij)}E_{11}+\alpha_{2}^{(ij)}E_{12}+\alpha_{3}^{(ij)}E_{21}+\alpha_{4}^{(ij)}E_{22}.  $$
Then $ad H$ has a matrix representation (with respect to the above basis):
$$ adH=\left( \begin{array}{cccc} \alpha_{1}^{(11)} & \alpha_{1}^{(12)} & \alpha_{1}^{(21)} & \alpha_{1}^{(22)}\\ 
\alpha_{2}^{(11)} & \alpha_{2}^{(12)} & \alpha_{2}^{(21)} & \alpha_{2}^{(22)}\\ 
\alpha_{3}^{(11)} & \alpha_{3}^{(12)} & \alpha_{3}^{(21)} & \alpha_{3}^{(22)}\\ 
\alpha_{4}^{(11)} & \alpha_{4}^{(12)} & \alpha_{4}^{(21)} & \alpha_{4}^{(22)}
\end{array} \right). $$